Shopware 6.6 plugin with administration page
I'm trying to develop a plugin which will have an administration page. The plugin is installed, but when I'm navigating to the custom page URL I see only blank page without any error. In console there is only "Removing unpermitted intrinsics".
Can someone provide me url from where I can download some sample skeleton plugin with admin page?

A good reference is this actively developed open source plugin:
https://github.com/FriendsOfShopware/FroshTools
It is maintained by (among others) Shopware employees. So you can be sure of its quality.
